# Send data array to an AdaptiveCard with c#

Tags: .net, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

i'm trying to develop a dynamic adaptive card to mention users in Teams, but i having a problem to render data inside the template.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.0",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "$data": [
        { "name": "Matt" },
        { "name": "David" },
        { "name": "Thomas" }
      ],
      "text": "hi, <at>${name}</at>"
    }
  ],
  "msteams": {

    "entities": [
      {
        "type": "mention",
        "$data": [
          { "name": "Matt" },
          { "name": "David" },
          { "name": "Thomas" }
        ],
        "text": "<at>${name}</at>",
        "mentioned": {
          "id": "${name}",
          "name": "${name}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

if i use this template everything works fine, but i need to dinamically render the data, i serialized a json with the same $data structure with the name of the user mentioned but it doesn't render anything.

i tryed this way but doesn't work

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.0",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "$data": ${user}
      "text": "hi, <at>${name}</at>"
    }
  ],
  "msteams": {

    "entities": [
      {
        "type": "mention",
        "$data": ${user},
        "text": "<at>${name}</at>",
        "mentioned": {
          "id": "${name}",
          "name": "${name}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

here's the C# code that serialize the data value

```
            List<MentionUser> userMentionList = new List<MentionUser>();
            AdaptiveCardTemplate template = new AdaptiveCardTemplate(File.ReadAllText("Resources/Mention.json"));
            var json = new List<MentionedList>();

            foreach (var subscription in SubscriptionMentions)
            {
                var element = new MentionUser
                {
                    name = subscription,
                };

                userMentionList.Add(element);
            }
            
            json.Add(new MentionedList { instructions = userMentionList});
            string jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(json);
            var data = new
            {
                user = jsonString,
            };
            string cardJson = template.Expand("");
            var card = SerializeCard(cardJson);
```

inside the jsonString i serialized this json string

```
[{"name":"username"},{"name":"username"}]}]
```

Can someonene please help to get rid of this problem?
Thank you a lot and have a nice day

Comment: We have also tried. When we are adding data statically then its working 2for textblock.
We are checking this internally. We will update you.

Answer (score 0):

We have tested using $data for array to send data in adaptive card dynamically.
It is supported for adaptive card textblock,factset etc.
Currently there is no support for sending dynamic array to entity property in msteams.
For mention user we have to repeat entity block not text block.

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/language